# Matching two dataframe columns but only on subset of data based on criteria

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[111,111,111,222,222,333,333],
                   "Name":['aaa','xxx','yyy','bbb','xxx','ccc','yyy']})

region = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[111,222,333,111,222,111],
                       "Name":['aaa','bbb','yyy','xxx','yyy','yyy'],
                       "Region": ['west','north','east','west','north','south']})
```

which produce the following tables:

```
df:
    ID  Name
0   111 aaa
1   111 xxx
2   111 yyy
3   222 bbb
4   222 xxx
5   333 ccc
6   333 yyy
```

```
region:
    ID  Name    Region
0   111 aaa     west
1   222 bbb     north
2   333 yyy     east
3   111 xxx     west
4   222 yyy     north
5   111 yyy     south
```

Essentially I want to map the Region column in `region` to the data in `df`. But as you can see both ID and Name have duplicate values. Therefore what I want to do is to first group the data based on ID, and then map the names one group at a time (there should not be any duplicate Names per ID group). For example, if we focus on ID 111, we get the following subsets:

```
df:
    ID  Name
0   111 aaa
1   111 xxx
2   111 yyy

region:
    ID  Name    Region
0   111 aaa     west
3   111 xxx     west
5   111 yyy     south
```

And now we can map Region from `region` to the data in `df`.

So far the only solution I have come up with is to manually subset `df` based on the ID groupings, perform the matching, and then concat the individual tables. But my actual dataset contains more than 100K records, which makes it a very slow task. Is there a way to map the values using the above logic but in one execution?

Comment: Just merge on ID and Name? `df.merge(region,on=['ID','Name'],how='left')`

Comment: Thanks this works. I'm new to Pandas, and now I think this might actually be a duplicate question based on the solution.

Comment: Yes . Actually it is :-) I will close it with a an answer you should read